# Compilation Error on my server on SmartStore App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, server, telerik, plesk

I have installed SmartStore on my server. everything is working fine except the add category module. when ever I try to Add or Edit any category an error pops saying :

> Compilation Error Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the
>   following methods or properties:
>   'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridToolBarCommandFactory.Template(System.Action>)'
>   and
>   'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridToolBarCommandFactory.Template(System.Func,object>)'

```
Line 441:   .ToolBar(commands => commands.Template(CategoryProductsGridCommands))
```

Please help me out. I m stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

After working on it, we got the solution for this. So kindly try like this.

Hope will work

```
.ToolBar(commands => commands.Template(pp=>GridCommands(pp)))
```